# webTarget.request returns type not acceptable by builder.method

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, unit-testing, jersey

I am trying to unittest an API REST function.

```
    builder = webTarget.request();
```

returns builder of the type

```
javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder
```

But if I take that builder and call builder.method("POST", entity) on it, the method called looks thus:

```
    public Response method(final String name, final Entity<?> entity) throws ProcessingException {
        requestContext.setMethod(name);
        storeEntity(entity);
        return new JerseyInvocation(this).invoke();
    }
```

And the last line uses as "this" different builder:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.Builder
```

And the run fails on that line.

I am looking at it and feel me crazy: How could it be, that the function is called as a member of one class, but when "this" is used in that method, absolutely different class is used?

Answer (score 0):

Both `Invocation` and `Invocation.Builder` are interfaces. The `WebTarget.request()` contract is to return `Invocation.Builder`. These are all interfaces we are talking about here; `WebTarget`, `Invocation`, `Invocation.Builder`. This is contract design by the JAX-RS specification. It is up the JAX-RS implementation to implement these interfaces. Jersey implementation are `JerseyWebTarget`, `JerseyInvocation`, and `JerseyInvociation.Builder`, respectively.

It's the same if I created something like this

```
public interface Model {}

public interface Service {
    Model getModel();
}

public ModelImpl implements Model {}

public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @Override
    public Model getModel() {
        return new ModelImpl();
    }
}
```

There's nothing special goin on here. The `Service` contract says that the `getModel()` method returns a `Model`, which is an interface, the actual return value will be of type `ModelImpl`, the implementation. Polymorphism in the works.

Comment: So, I should declare 'builder' as JerseyInvocation.Builder and after that builder.method will work?

Comment: No, `Invocation.Builder` is fine. There's no reason it shouldn't work. This is basic Java stuff. Nothing to do specifically with Jersey.

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error? I'm not sure what your question really is.